# loop for creating new column and fill with neighborhood row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have following df. I am going to dynamically create new columns based on number of date (day_number=2), and conditionally fill them based on "code" and "count"

*Current format:*

```
                    code  count    
id     date                                    
ABC1   2019-04-04    1    76             
       2019-04-05    2    82
```

*Desired matrix-like format:*

```
                    code  count    code1_day1   code1_day1   code1_day2  code2_day2  
id     date                                    
ABC1   2019-04-04    1    76      76            0            0          82           
       2019-04-05    2    82
```

I have done this but it fills the same for every column:

```
code=[1,2]

for date, new in df.groupby(level=[0]): 
    for col in range(day_number):  # day_number=2
        for lvl in code:
            new[f"day{col+1}_code1"]=new['count'].where(new['code']==1)
            new[f"day{col+1}_code2"]=new['count'].where(new['code']==2)
```

So many thanks for your help!

A biger example of the databse:

```
                 code  count   new-col1  new_col2  ......
id     date                                    
ABC1
       2019-04-04   1   76  76  0   79  0   82  0   83  0   88  0   55  3   65  6
       2019-04-05   1   79  79  0   82  0   83  0   88  0   55  3   65  6   101 10
       2019-04-06   1   82  82  0   83  0   88  0   55  3   65  6   101 10  120 14
       2019-04-07   2   83  83  0   88  0   55  3   65  6   101 10  120 14  0   0
       2019-04-08   1   88  88  0   55  3   65  6   101 10  120 14  0   0   0   0
       2019-04-09   1   55  55  3   65  6   101 10  120 14  0   0   0   0   10  0
       2019-04-09   2   3   65  6   101 10  120 14  0   0   0   0   10  0       
       2019-04-10   1   65  101 10  120 14  0   0   0   0   10  0               
       2019-04-10   2   6   120 14  0   0   0   0   10  0                       
       2019-04-11   1   101 0   0   0   0   10  0
```

Comment: For the row: `2019-04-05    2    82` and everything below it, you are going to fill `code1_day1   code2_day1   code1_day2  code2_day2` with `None`'s?

Comment: That's is true for current format. If there is more date below, then those date fill the top of themselves which is where you just referred. Many thanks.

Comment: Would an actual matrix work better for you? I'm also a bit confused on how it would look if you have a third date then, could you provide an example, or would it still just have all the values on the first line?

Comment: You are right, it is confusing. I try to edit the post, and would wait for any help. Many thanks.

Comment: Please see the biger example of the edited post. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the new filled data horizontally to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

- your sample data is not so usable so I've simulated
- considering differently,  the data is grouped, hence `groupby()` **ID** in index and **code**
- `apply()` after a `groupby()` gets passed a dataframe, build required columns on this dataframe

```
d = pd.date_range("01-jan-2021","03-jan-2021")
df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({"ID":"ABC1","date":d,"code":1,"count":np.random.randint(20,50, len(d))}),
    pd.DataFrame({"ID":"ABC1","date":d,"code":2,"count":np.random.randint(20,50, len(d))})
]).sort_values(["ID","date","code"], ascending=[True,False,True]).set_index(["ID","date"])

# pad an array with NaN to same length as second iterable
def nppad(a, s):
    return np.pad(a.astype(float), (0,len(s)-len(a)), "constant", constant_values=np.nan)

df2 = df.groupby(["ID","code"]).apply(lambda dfa: dfa.assign(**{f"code{dfa.iloc[0,0]}_day{i+1}":
                                                                nppad(dfa["count"].values[i:],dfa) 
                                                          for i in range(len(dfa))}))
```

#### output

```
                 code  count  code1_day1  code1_day2  code1_day3  code2_day1  code2_day2  code2_day3
ID   date                                                                                           
ABC1 2021-01-03     1     40        40.0        38.0        46.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
     2021-01-03     2     37         NaN         NaN         NaN        37.0        33.0        33.0
     2021-01-02     1     38        38.0        46.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
     2021-01-02     2     33         NaN         NaN         NaN        33.0        33.0         NaN
     2021-01-01     1     46        46.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
     2021-01-01     2     33         NaN         NaN         NaN        33.0         NaN         NaN
```